# How to track a settlement visa appeal?

Tags: united-kingdom

My wife's settlement visa application was refused, but they gave the right to appeal. We have done this and sent the suggested supporting documents. However, it's now been 7 weeks and we have heard nothing from them.

How to track this? Is there a contact number we can call?

We don't live in the UK so it's not so easy.

Answer (score 2):

It can take up to 12 weeks for the visa section to send your appeal bundle to the Tribunal, another 6-8 weeks, or longer, for a hearing (either oral or on paper without an oral hearing). Note that the office hours are GMT (GMT+1 during British Summer Time from the last Sunday in March to the last Sunday in October).

> [Contact the tribunal](https://www.gov.uk/immigration-asylum-tribunal) if you have any questions about your appeal. The tribunal can’t give you legal advice.
>
> First-tier Tribunal (Immigration and Asylum Chamber)
>  customer.service@hmcts.gsi.gov.uk
>   Telephone: 0300 123 1711 
>   Monday to Friday, 8:30am to 5pm
>   [Find out about call charges](https://www.gov.uk/call-charges)